# Add space between authors with multiple middle initials with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the IEEE style with biblatex. I have an article with an author with multiple middle initials. Unfortunately, the spacing between the middle initials are lost:

[image: J. R.R. A. Martins etc.]

Here is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@Article{Martins2003,
    author  = {Martins, Joaquim R. R. A. and Sturdza, Peter and Alonso, Juan J.},
    title   = {The complex-step derivative approximation},
    journal = {ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software},
    year    = {2003},
    volume  = {29},
    number  = {3},
    pages   = {245--262}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{\addnbthinspace}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't happen with `biber`. Perhaps it's a bug. Can you switch away from `bibtex`?

Comment: Good observation. I can use `biber` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This was a bug in `biblatex` 3.11 and earlier which has been resolved in `biblatex` 3.12. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/806 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/808. Update your TeX distribution if you are having troubles with this issue.

You should be able to control the space between all name initials with `\bibinitdelim`, but as your MWE shows this does not always work.

When compiled with BibTeX the `.bbl` file contains

```
giveni={J\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim R\bibinitperiod
  R\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim A\bibinitperiod},
```

which means that for some reason BibTeX does not add a `\bibinitdelim` between the two `R`s.

Internally, what happens is that BibTeX's normal name parsing and abbreviating routine adds  `.~` or `.` (a `.` and a space) and that is then transformed back into `\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim` or `\bibinitperiod`, respectively. [`btxhak`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxhak.pdf) explains that BibTeX decides itself whether to put a space or a non-breaking space (p. 9):

> BibTeX puts default strings between tokens of a name part: For whole tokens
>   it uses either a space or a tie, depending on which one it thinks is best, and for abbreviated tokens it uses a period followed by either a space or a tie.

If I compile your example with Biber, I get

```
giveni={J\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim R\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim R\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim A\bibinitperiod}
```

and consequently `\bibinitdelim` works as expected.

So this seems to be an issue with the BibTeX backend when used with `biblatex-bst`, I have opened an issue about this at the `biblatex` bugtracker: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/806

For now I can only advise to use Biber

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Martins2003,
    author  = {Martins, Joaquim R. R. A. and Sturdza, Peter and Alonso, Juan J.},
    title   = {The complex-step derivative approximation},
    journal = {ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software},
    year    = {2003},
    volume  = {29},
    number  = {3},
    pages   = {245--262}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{\addnbthinspace}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "J. R. R. A. Martins, P. Sturdza, and J. J. Alonso, “The complex-step derivative approximation,” ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, vol. 29, no. 3, pp. 245–262, 2003." with thin spaces between all initials]